# 2 line menu with css

Tags: css

It is probably easy to implement, but hard to name it. I am struggling to display this layout:

```
<ul class='menu'>
  <li>
    <a>item1</a>
    <ul class='submenu'> ... </ul>
  <li>
  <li><a>item2</a></li>
</ul>
```

in 2 horizontal lines: first line is ul.menu and second line is ul.submenu

Css:

```
ul.menu
{
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}
ul.menu li {
  display: inline;
}
ul.submenu {
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Is there a way to do it without position:absolute, so that menu container is in the flow of the document (there is no gap is submenu isn't present)?

Comment: Any css code you played around with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHFT4/2/) for this.

If I understand the problem correctly, you want a two-line menu, the submenu of which is still in the document flow, so the page will adjust when there is no submenu.

The catch is this: Without `position: absolute`, the parent `<li>` elements will expand to contain the submenu `<ul>` elements. This will leave your top-level menu items will odd spacing, depending on the width of your submenu elements.

If this isn't a problem, then the above jsFiddle should solve the issue. If it is a problem, then there is a little more work to do (and I don't have a solution quite yet).

Comment: Thanks for that, but this spacing is really a problem.

Comment: So, you want equally-spaced top-level elements, regardless of the content of the second-level elements? If so, my question is "what happens when second level elements run together?"

Answer (score 1):

Check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345039/multilevel-menu-navigation/4346178#4346178), I think it's similar to what you want.

EDIT: sorry, missed the css only idea, here's what I would do:

```
.submenu{ display:none;}
li:hover .submenu{ display: block;}
```

Comment: I don't think he wants a hover-style dropdown menu. I think he's looking for a submenu that is always displayed when it exists.

Comment: Can you post a version that works the wrong way, or with position absolute? I obviously don't understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Use the following updated CSS. It will work perfectly.

```
ul.menu {
    height: 20px;
}
ul.menu li {
    display: inline;
    float:left;
}
ul.submenu {
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work perfectly, there are still these awful gaps in the first line. I don't think it can be solved with position absolute.